# android Unsupported File type while installing apk from sdcard

Tags: android, file, apk

I have created 1 APK with version ***1.1*** from ***1***.  I have created its APK and put in the ***SD card***.

Now I want to install it but it tells me `Unsupported file type`, while the name contains only alpha characters only.. what is problem?

I have done this in my ***manifest.xml*** file:

```
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.1"
```

I have also done `Settings-> Application` and tick "Allow installation of non-market application".

Comment: Whats the file name of the apk on the sd card? How do you try to install it?

Comment: it name is wallpapershd and i am trying by clicking this apk

Comment: probably the file extension is not ".apk". make a 'adb shell ls' to check?

Answer (score 1):

The file must have an `.apk` extension to be recognized as apk. Change the name to `wallpapershd.apk`.